# BigQuery: append records from another table based on fields conditions

Tags: google-bigquery, append, union

I want to concatenate two tables vertically in BigQuery, which can be easily done using UNION ALL, like:

```
 SELECT
      t1.column1, 
      t1.column2, 
      t1.column3
    FROM
      `project.database.table1` as t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      t2.column1, 
      t2.column2, 
      t2.column3
    FROM
      `p21-project.database.table2` as t2
```

BUT I want to **exclude** the t2 rows WHENEVER:

*t2.column2=t1.column2 AND t1.column1=X*

Otherwise always append.

How to implement this?

Comment: You need to split the task into two steps. First you join t2 with t1 to filter t1. Samuel gave you the code

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do what I need (I hope the question was clear) using UNION ALL. I simply had to exclude things with a subquery like this:

```
  SELECT
  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t1.column3
FROM
  `project.database.table1` as t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  t2.column1,
  t2.column2,
  t2.column3
FROM
  `project.database.table2` as t2
WHERE
  t2.column2 NOT IN (
  SELECT
    t1.column2
  FROM
    `project.database.table1`
  WHERE
    t1.column1 = X)
```

Basically in the subquery I take all the column2 values from t1 where column1 = X, and then exclude all those values in the t2 table from the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

You can join table A to table B to identify douplicated rows.

First create some sample data in `testA` and `testB`. This part of the query can be ignored for answer.

```sql
With 
testA as (Select x col1, x+1 col2, "X" colX, "tableA" col3 from unnest([1,2,3,4,5]) as x),
testB as (Select x col1, x+20 col2, "Y", "tableB" from unnest([3,4,8,9]) as x),

tableA_filted as (Select col1 from testA where colX="X" group by 1),

tableB as (
  Select B.* from testB as B
  left join tableA_filted as A
  on A.col1=B.col1
  where A.col1 is null
)


SELECT * from testA
Union ALL
SELECT * from tableB
```

Since you know that not the complete table A is relevant, filtering this table and keep only the relevant columns in `tableA_filted`. The `group by 1` prevents duplicated entries. Then left join this to table B and keep only the rows where this join failed.

For many scenarios a `full join` is a better solution than an `union all`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't fully understand your code as I'm not familiar with nesting and unnesting fields. In any case I found the way to do it with UNION ALL. It was actually quite simple, I'm sorry if I haven't asked the question clearly enough. I posted my answer below.